# Is there a USB only file sync tool?

Tags: sync

I've been looking for a tool that will sync to/from an android device running Android 4.4.4 - so it's using MTP when I connect to my computer (running Windows 7) through a USB connection.

There are various options that require a drive letter, but MTP doesn't have those.

There are various options that use wi-fi and a through-the-internet solution, but I don't want to use the internet for this, I can copy files by hand so there must be SOME way of syncing.  Also, I want to use it with pretty big files so I was hoping there would be something that used file deltas. If I wanted to go through the net I would consider RSync, but I don't want to.

Ideally I would prefer something free and open source, but I can't find anything at -all-... Am I using the wrong search terms? (android, sync, usb, mtp, "open source", mix as desired.)  There are lots of similar questions on here, but as far as I can see they're all answered with a wi-fi sync tool instead of something USB specific.

Comment: `rsync` isn't just for internet connections: it works on mounted filesystems too. I don't understand why it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: What phone do you have? Likely the manufacturer's software suite can do this.

Comment: I have a Nexus 7.  I wasn't aware that rsync could be persuaded to work without an internet connection - could you provide some more details on that please? Perhaps as an answer, in which case I may accept it if it turns out that it actually does meet my needs?

Comment: `rsync` just works like `cp` for basic use.